# micronaut convert request param to Instant or ZonedDateTime

Tags: micronaut

I am using Micronaut 1.3.4 and I am trying to convert an input to an Instant. I tried in many ways until now but without success. The following code shows just two cases I tried and neither worked.

I would like to convert the input date to either `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`

```
    @Get("/...")
    public List<Obj> method(
//            @Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
//                    Instant startDateTime,
            @Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    LocalDate endDateTime
    ) {
```

I would like to use ISO 8601 if possible.

inputs I tried with:

```
2013-02-04
2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z
...
```

The output I get is:

```
"message": "Required argument [LocalDate endDateTime] not specified",
```

My fallback is:

```
        String startDateTime

        Instant parse = Instant.parse(startDateTime);
        OffsetDateTime parse = OffsetDateTime.parse(startDateTime);
```

But I would still like to know how to do it with Micronaut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can pass `LocalDateTime` as a query parameter in Micronaut:

```java
@Get("/local")
public String local(@Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") @QueryValue LocalDateTime time) {
    return "Time " + DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(time);
}
```

Example curl call with the result:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/local?time=2020-04-13T21:13:59
Time 2020-04-13T21:13:59
```

You can use `LocalDateTime` when the time zone is always the same. And you can convert it into `Instant` like this `time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()`.

When the time zone can be different and must be part of the input time, then you can use `ZonedDateTime` parameter like this:

```java
@Get("/zoned")
public String method(@Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") @QueryValue ZonedDateTime time) {
    return "Time " + DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(time);
}
```

Where conversion into `Instant` is simle: `time.toInstant()`

Example curl call with the result:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/zoned?time=2020-04-13T21:13:59.123-0100
Time 2020-04-13T21:13:59.123-01:00
```

When you enter the time query parameter in a bad format (missing fraction of seconds and zone offset here) then it behaves like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/zoned?time=2020-04-13T21:13:59
{"message":"Required QueryValue [time] not specified","path":"/time","_links":{"self":{"href":"/example/zoned?time=2020-04-13T21:13:59","templated":false}}}
```

---

You can also use time as a part of the request path:

```java
@Get("/local/{time}")
public String local(@Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime time) {
    return "Time from request path " + DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(time);
}
```

Then the example curl call will be:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/local/2020-04-13T21:13:59
Time from request path 2020-04-13T21:13:59
```

When you enter the time in path in a bad format (unwanted fraction of seconds here) then it behaves like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/local/2020-04-13T21:13:59.111
{"message":"Failed to convert argument [time] for value [2020-04-13T21:13:59.111] due to: Text '2020-04-13T21:13:59.111' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19","path":"/time","_links":{"self":{"href":"/example/local/2020-04-13T21:13:59.111","templated":false}}}
```

Comment: I tried `@Format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") @QueryValue ZonedDateTime startDateTime` but without success. I still get `"Required QueryValue [startDateTime] not specified"`. `curl 'http://localhost:8080/.../...?startDateTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00%2B03:00&endDateTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00%2B03:00'`

Comment: Yes, because your format pattern requires also fraction of seconds. Add it (`.000`) into your curl request: `?startDateTime=2020-04-14T00:00:00.000%2B0300&endDateTime=2020-04-15T00:00:00.000%2B0300`. Or you can change the required format on `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` and then fraction of seconds is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way of doing this. The `@Format`annotation is problematic because it can't support all of the formats that the java classes such as OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime support.

If you have for example this method:

```java
@Get("/local")
public String local(@QueryValue OffsetDateTime time) {
    return "Time " + time.toString();
}
```

To make it support ISO8601, modify your `Application.java` (or create a new class) containing:

```java
@Context
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // starts micronaut
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void addPathConverter(ConversionService<DefaultConversionService> conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(String.class, OffsetDateTime.class, (in) ->
                OffsetDateTime.parse(in));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Micronaut 3 the recommended way of resolving this, with the flexibility of
multiple formats, is by adding a custom type converter.

An example implementation for `OffsetDateTime` could be:

```
@Singleton
public class OffsetDateTimeConverter implements TypeConverter<String, OffsetDateTime> {

    @Override
    public Optional<OffsetDateTime> convert(String inputDateTime, Class<OffsetDateTime> targetType, ConversionContext context) {
        if (inputDateTime != null) {
            try {
                var offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputDateTime);
                return Optional.of(offsetDateTime);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                context.reject(inputDateTime, e);
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

This can be viewed in the [3.2.7 documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/3.2.7/guide/index.html#customTypeConverter) (and others).